# WCF Soap Formatter

Tags: wcf

I have the following class generated from svcutl.. using a wsdl. Using the wsdl, xsd's provided by the third party svcutil generated a class file.

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "http://someURL/2008")]
public partial class DocImgIdxType_Type
{

    private string valueField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()]
    public string Value
    {
        get
        {
            return this.valueField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.valueField = value;
        }
    }
}
public partial class DocImgIdx_CType
{

    private DocImgIdxType_Type docImgIdxTypeField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public DocImgIdxType_Type  DocImgIdxType
    {
        get
        {
            return this.docImgIdxTypeField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.docImgIdxTypeField= value;
        }
    }
```

The soap XMl gets generated in this way.

```
<d4p1:DocImgIdx_CType>
    <d4p1:docImgIdxTypeField>
        <d4p1:valueField>Document Type</d4p1:valueField>
    </d4p1:docImgIdxTypeField>
</d4p1:DocImgIdx_CType>
```

But the service is expecting a XML which looks like this

```
<DocImgIdx>
    <DocImgIdxType>Document Type</DocImgIdxType>
</DocImgIdx>
```

Why is the response being generated with docImgIdxTypeField private member of the DocImgIdxType_Type  class?. How do I remove valueField tags.. I have tried using [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("..")] but not there yet. Can this be done using formatter or do I need custom message encoder? If there is a straightforward way to change the response I would like to do that.

Comment: If you have no control over  your service, you could try to replace the model generated by the util with your customized model and also change the client interface that uses the old model, if the generated message matches the xsd, there should no problem, please don't forget to backup your original code.   Also, you could use XmlElementAttribute,XmlTextAttribute and so on to format the message, but this requires you to use XmlSerializer to serialize data. Please refer to [this link](http://blog.dlwelch.com/wcf-including-xml-attributes-in-your-datacontract/)

Comment: Thank you for that link.